# Set interval in kendo-timepicker

Tags: angular, kendo-angular-ui, kendo-timepicker

I use kendo-timepicker with angular 5. I need to set the time interval dynamically based on the value chosen in the drop down. By default, interval is set to 1 minute.

If I select 15 minutes in the drop down, then kendo-timepicker interval should be like 15,30,45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the interval of the of the `kendo-timepicker` component by utilizing the `steps` input. ([Docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/timepicker/incremental-steps/))

The `steps` input allows you to customize the steps for

- the **hour** value
- the **minute** value
- the **second** value

by assigning an object.

**Example**

```
<kendo-timepicker
    [steps]="{ hour: 1, minute: 15, second: 15}">
</kendo-timerpicker>
```

It's also possible to change the interval of e.g. the minute value by linking it to a variable. ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-42443903?file=app/app.component.ts))

Answer (score 0):

After trying examples from different sources. This is how I solved it.
using [steps] in kendo-timepicker

```
  <kendo-timepicker name="time" [steps]="interval" [value]="time"></kendo-timepicker>
```

in component.ts

```
 public interval: any = { hour: 1, minute: 15};
```